# Button click event handler before page load

Tags: asp.net

I will describe my problem  in simple way so it's not exactly what I'm trying to do but the idea is the same.Here is the problem:
I create dynamic   buttons from code behind.I get some id from query string,create button with that id ,dynamic add event handler to click event,and add button to placeholder.I store the list of id-s in session and in page load method recreate these buttons and add to placeholder.One of the id-s is  CurrentId and it's also stored in session.Buttons click handler do something like this

```
Button b=(Button)sender;
Session["CurrentId"]=Convert.ToInt32(b.ID);
```

In page load when I create buttons I want to set button text property different from others if `id==Convert.ToInt32(Session["CurrentId"])` when list of id-s are gotten from session.But problem is that click event handler is called after page load,and when I create buttons in page load ,CurrentId in session hasn't been channged by click event handler.Can you suggest any solution to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to update the buttons you have dynamically created after the click event has fired. Why not just change the button text within the click event as you have described?

i.e.

```
protected void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((Button)sender).Text = "Custom text for active button";
}
```

Also, you can always update the buttons on the PreRender event which occurs after the control click events but before the controls are served back down to the client.

Comment: @unknown: Make sure that you learn the ASP .Net page lifecycle properly, it's invaluable knowledge for these type of problems. Use the "SILVER" accronym to easily remember the stages. You can read about it here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNET_Page_Lifecycle.aspx